# RequiredField Validator not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to fire an ASP.NET required field validator as given below. I don't want the JavaScript function to fire unless and until the required field validator returns true. In my case, I am firing on button click and it doesn't return anything.

**Asp.net Code**

```
<div class="login_txt">
    Email ID<span class="asterisk">*</span>:
</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Style="width: 169px;" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:TextBox>
<div>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVtxtEmailId_ExistingUser" Font-Size="Smaller" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Email-ID"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevtxtEmailId_ExistingUser" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Font-Size="Smaller" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email-ID not in correct Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>                      

<div id="f2" class="text" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
    <div class="login_txt">
        Password<span class="asterisk">*</span> :
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVtxtPassword" Font-Size="Smaller" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="h5"></div>
<div id="f3" style="padding-left: 115px; padding-top: 10px">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_login" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login"  CssClass="login_btn" ImageUrl="images/Reg-login.png" OnClientClick="return ValidateLogin();" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ValidateLogin(){
        if (Page.IsValid) {
             alert('valid');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid');                 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: mention validation group in `RFVtxtEmailId_ExistingUser` validator and all other validators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your HTML, I can see that you haven't mentioned two things.

1. You didn't added the `ValidationGroup="Login"` to your Validation controls
2. You haven't added the `CausesValidation="true"` attribute to your button

For the full reference, have a look below:-

```
<div class="login_txt">
    Email ID<span class="asterisk">*</span>:</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Style="width: 169px;" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:TextBox>
<div>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVtxtEmailId_ExistingUser" ValidationGroup="login"
        Font-Size="Smaller" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Display="Dynamic"
        ForeColor="Red" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Email-ID"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevtxtEmailId_ExistingUser" ValidationGroup="login"
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Font-Size="Smaller"
        ControlToValidate="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
        runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email-ID not in correct Format"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</div>
</div>
<div id="f2" class="text" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
    <div class="login_txt">
        Password<span class="asterisk">*</span> :
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <div>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVtxtPassword" ValidationGroup="login" Font-Size="Smaller"
            ControlToValidate="txtPassword" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Please Enter Password"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="h5">
</div>
<div id="f3" style="padding-left: 115px; padding-top: 10px">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_login" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login"
        CssClass="login_btn" ImageUrl="images/Reg-login.png" OnClientClick="return ValidateLogin();" />
</div>
```

Hope that helps you

Have a look at the below screenshot:-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it without scripts: by giving

[CausesValidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)="true" and [ValidationGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)="someGroupName"

to your  `<asp:ImageButton/>` and also ValidationGroup="FormValidation"` to your validators:

Answer (score 1):

Mention `ValidationGroup` in every asp Validator as follows:

```
<div class="login_txt">Email ID<span class="asterisk">*</span>:</div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Style="width: 169px;" runat="server" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:TextBox>
<div>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVtxtEmailId_ExistingUser" Font-Size="Smaller" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Email-ID" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RevtxtEmailId_ExistingUser" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"   
Font-Size="Smaller" ControlToValidate="txtEmailId_ExistingUser" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Email-ID not in correct Format" ValidationGroup="login"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></div>
```

This will work. and if validation fails; then only `JS` function will be called.